# Flat edges in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, vector

So i was just toying around with inkscape, trying to make a nice thing for my friend. When i got to the horns though, i couldn't make their tips sharp and they came out looking flat. Is there a way to fix this maybe?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adjusting the stroke join behavior is possible on both shapes and paths. In Inkscape,

1. Select your shape/path
2. Go to the *Fill and Stroke* panel
3. Open the *Stroke style* tab
4. Set the join behavior to *Miter join*, which is the sharp square corner on the right
5. Depending on the size of your shape, you may need to increase the number in the box to the right. The hover text calls it the *Maximum length of the miter (in units of stroke width). The default is "4", but you can set it as high as needed to get the sharp edge.

If this does not work for you, you will need to provide additional information about how you're making that shape.

[image: Inkscape tools for making a sharp corner]

Answer (score 1):

Change the mitre join setting in the Stroke Style panel.  The actual mitre value you need to choose will depend on how acute the angle is.

[image]